# Compute $\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{ \cos(2nx) }{ a^2 + \cos^2 x} dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Compute the integral
$$I_n=\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{ \cos(2nx) }{ a^2 + \cos^2 x} dx$$
where $n$ is any integer.

Using trig identities to evaluate special cases I found answers for $n=0$ and $n=1$.

For $n=0$
$$I_0=\frac{2\pi}{ a \sqrt{a^2 +1}}$$

For $n=1$
$$I_1=2\pi\frac{ 2a( \sqrt{a^2 +1} - a ) -1 }{ a \sqrt{a^2 +1}}$$

How do I find a generic answer for any integer n?

Comment: Please add some context.  Also, is this a homework question?

Comment: Hint: Consider $I_1 = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{cos(2nx)}{a^2 + cos^2x}dx$ and $I_2 = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{sin(2nx)}{a^2 + cos^2x}dx$. $I_1 + iI_2 = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{e^{i2nx}}{a^2 + cos^2x}dx = \oint_{|z|=1}\frac{z^{2n}}{a^2+\frac{(z+\frac{1}{z})^2}{4}}\,\frac{dz}{iz} = -4i\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{z^{2n+1}}{z^4+(4a^2+2)z^2+1}dz$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume $n\ge0$, $ a>0$ (wlog) and let $t=2x$. Then

$$I_n=\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{ \cos(2nx) }{ a^2 + \cos^2 x } dx
=2\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\cos(nt )}{{2a^2+1+\cos t}}dt
$$
Apply the Fourier series below and observe that only the term of $k=n$ survives the integration due to $\cos(nt ) $ in the numerator (the constant term does in the case of $n=0$)
$$\frac{1}{{2a^2+1+\cos t}}=
\frac1{2a\sqrt{1+a^2}}\left(1+2\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k (\sqrt{1+a^2}-a)^{2k}\cos (kx)\right)
$$
As a result, the integral yields
$$I_n= 2\pi (-1)^n \frac{(\sqrt{1+a^2}-a)^{2n}}{a\sqrt{1+a^2}}
$$

Comment: Solution does not look right for n=0 and n=1.

Comment: The missing $\pi$ in the answer is added.

Comment: Quanto, still does not look right. For n=1 I've been checking answers for different a, the integral computed numerically, and I don't see negative values while the answer above is negative.

Comment: Quanto, let's keep a as a variable. Using trig identities to evaluate special cases I found answers for n=0 and n=1. For n=0 I get $$I_0=2\pi/( a \sqrt{a^2 +1})$$. For n=1 I get $$I_1=2\pi( 2a( \sqrt{a^2 +1} - a ) -1 )/( a \sqrt{a^2 +1})$$. The n=1 answer does not agree with your answer.

Comment: @user130354 - your $I_1(a)$ can be written as $$-2\pi \frac{(\sqrt{1+a^2}-a)^{2}}{a\sqrt{1+a^2}}$$. So, they agree.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117096/discussion-between-user130354-and-quanto).

Comment: @user130354 You have to add $\tt @$ to ${\tt Quanto}$ such that he can see your comment. Like $\tt @Quanto$ at your comment beginning.

Comment: @ Felix, thanks and will do.